# Paypal API . How to remove the client address

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

Hi im developing on Paypal's Api and I was wondering how can I remove the buyer adress when he wants to buy a digital goods or something else.
Cuz if its like a logo , an image , or a sound the buyer doesnt need to know where he leaves...

When i've implemented paypal's button (a pop_up show off it does not show the adress of the buyer) otherwise when we are redirected to paypal before paying I have the summary of the buyer and I don't wanna see the buyer adress.

I'm building the ExpressCheckout payment API . With the methods 
1) SetExpressChecktout to set up the transaction
2) Redirect the customer to paypal ( its here i don't wanna have all the datas of the buyer)
3) GetExpressCheckout to obtain customer informations
4) Call DoExpressCheckout to complete the transaction

I have an example on the production where i work. But if you really need an example I will make an url just for you.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use PayPal Express Checkout for Digital Goods. It is specifically setup not to include shipping information. Here is the information:
[Digital Goods Express Checkout Integration Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/digital-goods/IntegratingExpressCheckoutDG/)

For code examples, here is the Integration Wizard for Digital Express Checkout. 
[Integration Wizard Digital Goods Express Checkout](https://devtools-paypal.com/integrationwizard/ecdigitalgoods/main.php)

The programming languages in the Integration Wizard are php and java.

Just in case you need it, here is additional information on setting your PayPal Account up for Digital Goods:
[PayPal Digital Goods Setup](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/digital-goods)